# How to get data from webservice that is returning array

Tags: javascript, react-native

Hi Every one I am trying to get data from webservice which is returning me XML.I used the Xml to JSON dependency to return me data in JSON but another problem is it is returning me the data in an array and the app cant display the data.But it comes out in the terminal just fine

Here is the image

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xDf7v.png)

```html
import React from "react";
import {StyleSheet,View,ActivityIndicator,FlatList,Text,TouchableOpacity} from "react-native";

export default class Source extends React.Component {
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
return {
  title: "Source Listing",
  headerStyle: {backgroundColor: "#fff"},
  headerTitleStyle: {textAlign: "center",flex: 1}
 };
};
constructor(props) {
 super(props);
 this.state = {
   loading: false,
   items:[]
  };

}
FlatListItemSeparator = () => {
return (
  <View style={{
     height: .5,
     width:"100%",
     backgroundColor:"rgba(0,0,0,0.5)",
}}
/>
);
}

renderItem=(data)=>
<TouchableOpacity style={styles.list}>
<Text style={styles.lightText}>{data.item.name}</Text>
<Text style={styles.lightText}>{data.item.email}</Text>
<Text style={styles.lightText}>{data.item.company.name}</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
render(){
 fetchdata()
 {
 if(this.state.loading){
  return( 
    <View style={styles.loader}> 
      <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#0c9"/>
    </View>
)}}
return(
 <View style={styles.container}>
 <FlatList
    data= {this.state.dataSource}
    ItemSeparatorComponent = {this.FlatListItemSeparator}
    renderItem= {item=> this.renderItem(item)}
    keyExtractor= {item=>item.id.toString()}
 />
</View>
)}
}
const parseString = require('react-native-xml2js').parseString;

    fetch('http://192.168.200.133/apptak_service/apptak.asmx/Get_Item_Master')
        .then(response => response.text())
        .then((response) => {
            parseString(response, function (err, result) {
                console.log(response)
            });
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.log('fetch', err)
            this.fetchdata();
        })

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#fff"
   },
  loader:{
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    backgroundColor: "#fff"
   },
  list:{
    paddingVertical: 4,
    margin: 5,
    backgroundColor: "#fff"
   }
});
```